# Get file extension from a url that doesn't include the extension

Tags: ruby

For example:

https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/9784fd51f1db751e9806a0620f1c432b?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG

If run this:

```
require 'open-uri'
local_path = 'app/assets/images/'

image_url = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/9784fd51f1db751e9806a0620f1c432b?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG'
image_name = image_url.match( /[&=-_\w:]+$/i ).to_s;
image_content = open(image_url).read.to_s
# image_extension = File.extname(image_content) # doesn't work


puts image_content

File.open( local_path + image_name + '.jpg' , 'wb') do |out_file|
    out_file.write(image_content)
end
```

The image is saved successfully, but I have to hardcode the '.jpg' to concatenate onto the end of the file name (look at the last but two line).

**The aim is to replace that `'.jpg'` with `image_extension` and for it to still work.**

Comment: https://rubygems.org/gems/magic, maybe.

Comment: Have you looked at the `Content-Type` header ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require "open-uri"
require "mime/types"

image_url = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/9784fd51f1db751e9806a0620f1c432b?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG'
image_download = open(image_url)
type = MIME::Types[image_download.content_type]
extension = type[0].extensions[0]
# => "png"
```